# MongoDB order by

Tags: mongodb, búsquedas

practicando con mongo

tengo una colección

```
   {
    "_id" : "158748",
    "data" : {
        "1" : {
            "tem" : 0,
            "sal" : 0,
        },
        "3" : {
            "tem" : 0,
            "sal" : 0,
        },        
       "4" : {
            "tem" : 0,
            "sal" : 0,
        },
        "2" : {
            "tem" : 0,
            "sal" : 0,
        }
    }
}
```

y para ordenarla en la consulta find()

```
db.getCollection('data').find({'_id':158748}).sort({"data":1 });
```

no da resultado vi otra

```
db.getCollection('data').find({$query:{'_id':158748}, $orderby:{"data":1 }});
```

pero da este error

```
Error: error: {
    "waitedMS" : NumberLong(0),
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "unknown top level operator: $query",
    "code" : 2
}
```

no se como se podria hacer para que de como resultado del find
con los valores de **"data"** ordenador por su llave

Comment: deseas ordenar por id?

Comment: por data, que salga, que data tenga dentro data: {1,2,3,4} y no data: {1,3,4,2}

Answer (score 0):

El problema que tienes es que estas escribiendo mal la query. Mete esta y dime si te funciona:

```
db.getCollection('data').find({"_id":"158748"}).sort({"data":1 });
```

Si te das cuenta, estas buscando por `{"_id":158748}` y en la que te he pasado es `{"_id":"158748"}`.

Comment: ese fallo es que escribí mal aquí, en el código esta bien.  todo son int